# How can I create a formfield which displays two values in a Mask?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I need a sort of textfield which allows me to apply a mask which

1. filters the input
2. applies some default text

Here is a example to what it should look like while typing

[image]

and after the field blurs

[image]

Both values need to be stored in separated properties while the whole field need to be set with a object and need to return one. I already get it working to have a field which I can set with an object and which returns one but I have no idea how I can apply a mask.

Any help or advice is appreciated!

Edit:

Here is what I got so far: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/C72z5/3/)

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.Field', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Base',
    alias: 'widget.maskfield',

    initComponent: function() {
      this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    setValue: function(value) {
        var me = this;
        me.setRawValue(me.valueToRaw(value));
        return me.mixins.field.setValue.call(me, value);
    },
    valueToRaw: function(value) {
        var empty = {},
            me = this,
            len = this.properties.length,
            i = 0;
        for(;i<len;i++) {
            var prop = this.properties[i];
            empty[prop] = this.value ? this.value[prop] || 0 : 0;
        }

        return Ext.value(value, empty);
    },
    transformRawValue: function(value) {
        var v = this.getValue(),
            s = v.split(',');
        return s[0] + 'J' + s[1] + 'M';
    },
    setRawValue: function(value) {
        var me = this,
            value = Ext.value(me.transformRawValue(value), '');
        me.rawValue = value;

        // Some Field subclasses may not render an inputEl
        if (me.inputEl) {
            me.inputEl.dom.value = value;
        }
        return value;
    },
    getValue: function() {
        var me = this,
            len = this.properties.length,
            i = 0,
            value = '';
        for(;i<len;i++) {
            if(!this.value)
                value = '';
            else if (!value)
                value = this.value[this.properties[i]];
            else
                value += ','+this.value[this.properties[i]];
        }
        return value        
    },
    // should overwrite the mixin
    isEqual: function(obj1,obj2) {
      var me = this,
          p;
      for(p in obj1) {
          if(typeof(obj2[p])=='undefined') {return false;}
      }

      for(p in obj1) {
          var prop;
          if (prop = obj1[p]) {
              switch(typeof(prop)) {
                  case 'object':
                      if (!me.equals(prop, obj2[p])) { return false; }
                      break;
                  case 'function':
                      return false;
                      break;
                  default:
                      if (prop != obj2[p]) { return false; }
              }
          } else {
              if (obj2[p])
                  return false;
          }
      }

      for(p in obj2) {
          if(typeof(obj1[p])=='undefined') {return false;}
      }

      return true;
    }

});
```

Comment: if you were to do field.getValue() from the above example, what is the expected return?

Comment: Also, can you provide the code you've already done for this field?

Comment: @Reimius I edited my question. Please take a look

Comment: It looks like there is a ton of logic that this field is doing.  What are the requirements exactly?

Comment: @Reimius Getting/setting with a JS object where the object properties get defined in the `properties` array which also defines the order in the field. Now I want to be able to apply a sort of mask for each of these properties which first allow me to format the given input (calculate, add sufix, etc), second filter invalid inputs and third apply a visible mask to make typing self explaining (last is not so important)